# VBA - Output Slide Name to a text box PowerPoint

Tags: vba, export, powerpoint, slide, names

I am trying to copy the slide name (not the title) for a slide to appear within a text box on the same slide.  I can get the entire list of slide names to output to an external file or appear in the Immediate Window.  Is there some sort of copy/paste syntax or isolated output that will work?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation for stackoverflow questions is that you show your working code, so people can see what you've tried, adding context to the question that you're asking. However maybe try something like this, which simply adds a textbox containing the slide name to each slide:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SlideNames()

    Dim WorkSlide As Slide
    Dim WorkTextBox As Shape
        
    For Each WorkSlide In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        Set WorkTextBox = WorkSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 100, 20)
        WorkTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = WorkSlide.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That did what I needed.  Thank you so much.  I was trying to re-engineer somebody's code from 9 years ago and got completely lost in the process.